# how to append search to end of current url

Tags: php, html

How would I append the search string to the end of the url instead of deleting the current posts

```
<input class="searchBox" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Here">
<input type="submit" value="">
```

I have this at the moment and it deletes the other Post variables at the end of the url, but what I want it to do is append it to the end

So for example, I have page.php?id=123 .. the user searches and I want it to display page.php?id=123&search=text, but at the moment it replaces it and does page.php?search=text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$_GET['id']."'>;
```

Into the form

Answer (score 2):

you can insert a hidden input before the other inputs. Also your form must submit using get to achieve what you are looking for.

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
    <input class="searchBox" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Here">
    <input type="submit" value="Search"> 
</form>
```